# Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError (getaddrinfo: No such host is known. ) while uploading image to s3 using paperclip for heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

## paperclip.rb

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = ':class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
```

## Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end
gem 'searchkick'
gem 'cocoon'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'foundation-rails'
gem 'tinymce-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.8'
gem 'haml'
gem 'font-awesome-rails', '~> 4.6', '>= 4.6.1.0'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'paperclip', '5.0.0.beta2'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'acts_as_votable'
gem 'masonry-rails', '~> 0.2.4'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.2', '>= 2.2.35'
gem 'foreman'
gem 'puma'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks', '~> 2.1'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

config/production.rb

```
   Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    :s3_region => ENV['AWS_REGION'],
    s3_credentials: {
      bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
      access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
  }
end
```

I am using `beta(5.0.0) of paperclip` with `aws-sdk ~>2.3`.Problem is like when I am trying to upload image to s3 using paperclip it giving above error in title. I have referenced [blog](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3) for setting things up.I don't think it work. Please Helpout I am stuck in this for like 2 days.Thank You in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

The blog post you cited is written for AWS SDK prior to version 2.0.  Since you are using gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.2', '>= 2.2.35', you will need to define the region.

So instead of

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
```

You would use

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_region] = 'us-west-2'
```

Be sure to reference the Paperclip documentation [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/UPGRADING) as it is up-to-date as of today.

Comment: I have reverted back to `gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.66.0'`. Can you help me out with this error `AWS::S3::Errors::AccessDenied (Access Denied`

Comment: Have you set the AWS Access Key Id and AWS Secret Access Key?  You can find more info in the AWS docs here:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/managing-aws-access-keys.html

Comment: There was problem with ENV variables.. Thank You !

Comment: Great to hear!  Please mark my answer as correct to help others as well. Glad I could help!

Comment: I have the same problem. Setting the region and removing and removing the host name didn't do anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please move bucket out of s3_credentials and we will need s3_host_name to access a documents from Amazon S3

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_region: ENV['AWS_REGION'],
  s3_host_name: ENV['AWS_HOST_NAME'],
  bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
  s3_credentials: {
    access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

Also make sure your IAM user has the right S3 permissions and you are using the right value for s3_region.

You can find a list of all S3 regions at the following link.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region